# Foreign Language Translation for Hamlet Act 5, Scene 2

Tags: translation

I'm currently translating this Japanese article, which quoted Hamlet Act 5, Scene 2.

The following are the original Hamlet context and its Japanese translation.

> **If it be now, 'tis not to come; if it be not to come, it will be
>   now; if it be not now, yet it will come**: the
>   readiness is all: since no man has aught of what he
>   leaves, what is't to leave betimes?
>
> **来るべきものは、今来なくともいずれは来る。今来れば、後には来ない。後に来なければ、今来るだけのこと。** 肝腎なのは覚悟だ。いつ死んだらいいか、そんなことは考えてみたところで、誰にも判りはしない。所詮、あなた任せさ。 (ハムレット、第5幕第2場)

It appears that they reordered/rearranged the sentence. My problem is that I'm not sure which English sentence correspond to the English translation of the Japanese one.

**English**

> **Sentence 1**: If it be now, 'tis not to come
>
> **Sentence 2**: if it be not to come, it will be now
>
> **Sentence 3**: if it be not now, yet it will come

**English Translation from Japanese** (word-by-word)

> **Sentence A:** The thing which must come, even if it doesn't come now, eventually it will.
>
> from 来るべきものは、今来なくともいずれは来る。
>
> **Sentence B:** If it comes now, it won't come later.
>
> from 今来れば、後には来ない。
>
> **Sentence C:** It it's not coming later, it should come now.
>
> from 後に来なければ、今来るだけのこと。

Some suggest that sentence 3=A, 1=B and 2=C, but I want to try asking in this forum.

---

The only reason I decided to ask in this forum, is because I could not even match English with English(translation). I can simply leave out the detail about Japanese, but I decided not to since I found that it is better to give as much detail as possible.

Thank you